# ladon throwing an AttributeError

Tags: python, soap, ladon

I'm trying to get ladon working, however, I don't seem to be able to define the service properly.

Specifically, even with a minimal test case, it's throwing

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\ladon\server\wsgi_application.py", line 332, in __call__
    self.import_services(self.service_list)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\ladon\server\wsgi_application.py", line 288, in import_services
    __import__(service)
  File "D:\Workspaces\Python\SOAPManager.py", line 20, in <module>
    @ladonize(PORTABLE_STRING, PORTABLE_STRING, rtype=PORTABLE_STRING)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\ladon\ladonizer\decorator.py", line 118, in decorator
    injector.__doc__ = ladon_method_info._doc
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_doc'
```

My Run.py contains:

```
from ladon.server.wsgi import LadonWSGIApplication
from os.path import abspath, dirname
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server


application = LadonWSGIApplication(
    ['SOAPManager'],
    [dirname(abspath(__file__))],
    catalog_name='API',
    catalog_desc='API Description')

httpd = make_server('0.0.0.0', 8004, application)
print("Listening on port 8004...")

# Respond to requests until process is killed
httpd.serve_forever()
```

And the minimal test case in SOAPManager.py:

```
from ladon.ladonizer import ladonize
from ladon.types.ladontype import LadonType
from ladon.compat import PORTABLE_STRING

@ladonize(PORTABLE_STRING, PORTABLE_STRING, rtype=PORTABLE_STRING)
def Authenticate(Username, Password):
    return "Test"
```

The error is being raised from within the `ladonize` decorator. It seems to be occuring when trying to build up the definition of the service. Specifically, in ladon the `decorator` calls `collection.add_service_method` which returns `None` instead of a method. I *think* it's failing a line-number check.

```
firstlineno = f.__code__.co_firstlineno
# get an ast-analyzed object of the source file
sinfo = self.source_info(src_fname)
...
for clsname,v in sinfo.items():
    if firstlineno>v[0] and firstlineno<=v[1]:
```

For some reason that check is failing so the method defaults to returning `None`.